# Asked why it failed import axios for testing

Tags: reactjs, testing, testcase

```
import React from "react";
import { render, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import axios from "axios";
import ax from "../conf/ax";
import conf from "../conf/main";
import AllCourse from "../pages/allCourse";

jest.mock("../conf/ax");
jest.mock("../conf/main");

describe("AllCourse component", () => {

  test("fetches likeMost data and renders course components", async () => {
    // Mocking the response for likeMost
    axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce({
      data: {
        data: [
          { id: 1, title: "Course 1" },
          { id: 2, title: "Course 2" },
        ],
      },
    });

    // Rendering the component
    const { getByText } = render(<AllCourse />);

    await waitFor(() => {
      // Expecting the course titles to be rendered
      expect(getByText("Course 1")).toBeInTheDocument();
      expect(getByText("Course 2")).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });

  test("fetches newest data and renders newest course components", async () => {
    // Mocking the response for newest
    axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce({
      data: {
        data: [
          { id: 3, title: "New Course 1" },
          { id: 4, title: "New Course 2" },
        ],
      },
    });

    // Rendering the component
    const { getByText } = render(<AllCourse />);

    // Waiting for the component to render
    await waitFor(() => {
      // Expecting the newest course titles to be rendered
      expect(getByText("New Course 1")).toBeInTheDocument();
      expect(getByText("New Course 2")).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });
});
```

I want to test 2 case, One is can render to get like most course. Next one, it get newest data.
I'm beginer to learn about this. So, I dont know how to write good test case code for react.
I try to removed import axios but It's not work. it's failed next import (mockAdapter)

Comment: Show the code of `AllCourse` component